# Extract query-object from a fasta file and store them in different fasta file, one per query gene

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I am running out of ideas to do this, and I will appreciate some help, please.I have 2 fasta files from two different bacterial strains with 1000 genes each. An example of files:

```
file A:                           fileB
    query seq.id                    query seq.id
    query seq                        query seq.id
    objA seq.id                     objB seq.id
    objA seq                          objB seq
    query_1 seq.id                query_1 seq.id                                              
    query_1 seq                    query_1 seq
    obj_1A seq.id                obj_1B seq.id
    obj_1A seq                    obj_1B seq
```

What I would like to do is to get it this:

```
   file_1                  file_2
 query seq.id          query_1 seq.id
  query seq              query_1 seq
obj seq.id                obj_1A seq. id
  obj seq                   obj_A seq
 objB seq.id             obj_1B seq.id
 objB seq                  obj_1B seq
```

But I just dont know how to split the fasta files. I was trying to do this using biopython SeqIO but I am quite lost.
I'm working in this code:

```
for file in files:  
    my_file=glob.glob(file + '/*.fa')
    #print my_file[1]
    filename='outfile%s.fasta'
    records=list(SeqIO.parse(my_file[1], 'fasta'))
    query_gene=records[0].id
    print query_gene
    for record in  range (0,len(records),2):


        with open(os.path.join('/home/results/files/', filename% query_gene), 'w') as output_handle:


            SeqIO.write(records, ouput_handle, 'fasta')
sorting_fasta_files()
```

This is not giving me the right output. It places all the genes in files when, and want 2 genes per file, query-obj.

Comment: The contents of the files you posted doesn't look like FASTA files (they don't contain lines starting with `>` and they don't contain sequences). Also, please post the contents of your sample files under each other (for easy copy/pasting) and not side-by-side.

Comment: Yes, they contained it as it is a fasta file. I didnt write for simplicity but I thought it was understood as I am speaking about fasta files.

Comment: Please always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the question you are asking. Now it is impossible for me to reproduce the problem you are having.